# Create View but get Warning: compiled but with compilation error in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

When i create a view I am getting this warning in Toad:

> Warning: compiled but with compilation error in oracle

This is my script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW APPS.KMI_OKP_TRACK_V
(
   NO_OKP,
   LINE,
   FBD_PSD,
   FBD_ASD,
   FBD_PCD,
   FBD_ACD,
   FBD_DD,
   FBD_BCD,
   MIX_PSD,
   MIX_ASD,
   MIX_PCD,
   MIX_ACD,
   MIX_DD,
   MIX_BCD,
   BPR_PSD,
   BPR_ASD,
   BPR_PCD,
   BPR_ACD,
   BPR_DD,
   BPR_BCD,
   BLD_PSD,
   BLD_ASD,
   BLD_PCD,
   BLD_ACD,
   BLD_DD,
   BLD_BCD,
   CAN_PSD,
   CAN_ASD,
   CAN_PCD,
   CAN_ACD,
   CAN_DD,
   CAN_BCD,
   BAG_PSD,
   BAG_ASD,
   BAG_PCD,
   BAG_ACD,
   BAG_DD,
   BAG_BCD,
   DPG_PSD,
   DPG_ASD,
   DPG_PCD,
   DPG_ACD,
   DPG_DD,
   DPG_BCD,
   SAC_PSD,
   SAC_ASD,
   SAC_PCD,
   SAC_ACD,
   SAC_DD,
   SAC_BCD,
   BPE_PSD,
   BPE_ASD,
   BPE_PCD,
   BPE_ACD,
   BPE_DD,
   BPE_BCD
)
AS
     SELECT   DISTINCT XX.NO_OKP,
                       XX.LINE                             --,XX.CREATION_DATE
                              ,
                       FBD.FBD_PSD,
                       FBD.FBD_ASD,
                       FBD.FBD_PCD,
                       FBD.FBD_ACD,
                       FBD.FBD_DD,
                       FBD.FBD_BCD,
                       MIX.MIX_PSD,
                       MIX.MIX_ASD,
                       MIX.MIX_PCD,
                       MIX.MIX_ACD,
                       MIX.MIX_DD,
                       MIX.MIX_BCD,
                       BPR.BPR_PSD,
                       BPR.BPR_ASD,
                       BPR.BPR_PCD,
                       BPR.BPR_ACD,
                       BPR.BPR_DD,
                       BPR.BPR_BCD,
                       BLD.BLD_PSD,
                       BLD.BLD_ASD,
                       BLD.BLD_PCD,
                       BLD.BLD_ACD,
                       BLD.BLD_DD,
                       BLD.BLD_BCD,
                       CAN.CAN_PSD,
                       CAN.CAN_ASD,
                       CAN.CAN_PCD,
                       CAN.CAN_ACD,
                       CAN.CAN_DD,
                       CAN.CAN_BCD,
                       BAG.BAG_PSD,
                       BAG.BAG_ASD,
                       BAG.BAG_PCD,
                       BAG.BAG_ACD,
                       BAG.BAG_DD,
                       BAG.BAG_BCD,
                       DPG.DPG_PSD,
                       DPG.DPG_ASD,
                       DPG.DPG_PCD,
                       DPG.DPG_ACD,
                       DPG.DPG_DD,
                       DPG.DPG_BCD,
                       SAC.SAC_PSD,
                       SAC.SAC_ASD,
                       SAC.SAC_PCD,
                       SAC.SAC_ACD,
                       SAC.SAC_DD,
                       SAC.SAC_BCD,
                       BPE.BPE_PSD,
                       BPE.BPE_ASD,
                       BPE.BPE_PCD,
                       BPE.BPE_ACD,
                       BPE.BPE_DD,
                       BPE.BPE_BCD
       FROM                              (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                                     RTRIM (
                                                        SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4),
                                                        'A'
                                                     )
                                                        no_okp,
                                                     ATTRIBUTE1 LINE --,CREATION_DATE
                                              FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                             WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                                     AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                              (TO_CHAR (
                                                                  SYSDATE - 7,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                               ),
                                                               TO_CHAR (
                                                                  SYSDATE - 8,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                               ))
                                          ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) XX
                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                         (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                                     RTRIM (
                                                        SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4),
                                                        'A'
                                                     )
                                                        no_okp,
                                                     attribute1 Line,
                                                     DECODE (batch_status,
                                                             '1', 'Inspect',
                                                             '2', 'Release',
                                                             '3', 'Complete',
                                                             'Close')
                                                        Batch_status,
                                                     CREATION_DATE,
                                                     PLAN_START_DATE FBD_PSD,
                                                     ACTUAL_START_DATE FBD_ASD,
                                                     PLAN_CMPLT_DATE FBD_PCD,
                                                     ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE FBD_ACD,
                                                     DUE_DATE FBD_DD,
                                                     BATCH_CLOSE_DATE FBD_BCD
                                              FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                             WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                                     AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                              (TO_CHAR (
                                                                  SYSDATE - 7,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                               ),
                                                               TO_CHAR (
                                                                  SYSDATE - 8,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                               ))
                                                     AND attribute1 = 'FAT BLEND'
                                          ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) FBD
                                      ON XX.NO_OKP = FBD.NO_OKP
                                   LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                      (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                                  RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4),
                                                         'A')
                                                     no_okp,
                                                  attribute1 Line,
                                                  DECODE (batch_status,
                                                          '1', 'Inspect',
                                                          '2', 'Release',
                                                          '3', 'Complete',
                                                          'Close')
                                                     Batch_status,
                                                  CREATION_DATE,
                                                  PLAN_START_DATE MIX_PSD,
                                                  ACTUAL_START_DATE MIX_ASD,
                                                  PLAN_CMPLT_DATE MIX_PCD,
                                                  ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE MIX_ACD,
                                                  DUE_DATE MIX_DD,
                                                  BATCH_CLOSE_DATE MIX_BCD
                                           FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                          WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                                  AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                               'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                           (TO_CHAR (
                                                               SYSDATE - 7,
                                                               'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                            ),
                                                            TO_CHAR (
                                                               SYSDATE - 8,
                                                               'MM/DD/YYYY'
                                                            ))
                                                  AND attribute1 = 'MIX'
                                       ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) MIX
                                   ON XX.NO_OKP = MIX.NO_OKP
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                   (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                               RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4),
                                                      'A')
                                                  no_okp,
                                               attribute1 Line,
                                               DECODE (batch_status,
                                                       '1', 'Inspect',
                                                       '2', 'Release',
                                                       '3', 'Complete',
                                                       'Close')
                                                  Batch_status,
                                               CREATION_DATE,
                                               PLAN_START_DATE BPR_PSD,
                                               ACTUAL_START_DATE BPR_ASD,
                                               PLAN_CMPLT_DATE BPR_PCD,
                                               ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE BPR_ACD,
                                               DUE_DATE BPR_DD,
                                               BATCH_CLOSE_DATE BPR_BCD
                                        FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                       WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                               AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                            'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                        (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                                         TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8,
                                                                  'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                               AND attribute1 = 'BASE POWDER'
                                    ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) BPR
                                ON XX.NO_OKP = BPR.NO_OKP
                             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                            RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A')
                                               no_okp,
                                            attribute1 Line,
                                            DECODE (batch_status,
                                                    '1', 'Inspect',
                                                    '2', 'Release',
                                                    '3', 'Complete',
                                                    'Close')
                                               Batch_status,
                                            CREATION_DATE,
                                            PLAN_START_DATE BLD_PSD,
                                            ACTUAL_START_DATE BLD_ASD,
                                            PLAN_CMPLT_DATE BLD_PCD,
                                            ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE BLD_ACD,
                                            DUE_DATE BLD_DD,
                                            BATCH_CLOSE_DATE BLD_BCD
                                     FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                    WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                            AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                         'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                     (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7,
                                                               'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                                      TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8,
                                                               'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                            AND attribute1 = 'BLEND'
                                 ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) BLD
                             ON XX.NO_OKP = BLD.NO_OKP
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                         RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A')
                                            no_okp,
                                         attribute1 Line,
                                         DECODE (batch_status,
                                                 '1', 'Inspect',
                                                 '2', 'Release',
                                                 '3', 'Complete',
                                                 'Close')
                                            Batch_status,
                                         CREATION_DATE,
                                         PLAN_START_DATE CAN_PSD,
                                         ACTUAL_START_DATE CAN_ASD,
                                         PLAN_CMPLT_DATE CAN_PCD,
                                         ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE CAN_ACD,
                                         DUE_DATE CAN_DD,
                                         BATCH_CLOSE_DATE CAN_BCD
                                  FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                                 WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                         AND TO_CHAR (creation_date,
                                                      'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                                  (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7,
                                                            'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                                   TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8,
                                                            'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                         AND attribute1 = 'CANNING'
                              ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) CAN
                          ON XX.NO_OKP = CAN.NO_OKP
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                      RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A') no_okp,
                                      attribute1 Line,
                                      DECODE (batch_status,
                                              '1', 'Inspect',
                                              '2', 'Release',
                                              '3', 'Complete',
                                              'Close')
                                         Batch_status,
                                      CREATION_DATE,
                                      PLAN_START_DATE BAG_PSD,
                                      ACTUAL_START_DATE BAG_ASD,
                                      PLAN_CMPLT_DATE BAG_PCD,
                                      ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE BAG_ACD,
                                      DUE_DATE BAG_DD,
                                      BATCH_CLOSE_DATE BAG_BCD
                               FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                              WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                      AND TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                               (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7,
                                                         'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                                TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8,
                                                         'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                      AND attribute1 = 'BAG'
                           ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) BAG
                       ON XX.NO_OKP = BAG.NO_OKP
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                   RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A') no_okp,
                                   attribute1 Line,
                                   DECODE (batch_status,
                                           '1', 'Inspect',
                                           '2', 'Release',
                                           '3', 'Complete',
                                           'Close')
                                      Batch_status,
                                   CREATION_DATE,
                                   PLAN_START_DATE DPG_PSD,
                                   ACTUAL_START_DATE DPG_ASD,
                                   PLAN_CMPLT_DATE DPG_PCD,
                                   ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE DPG_ACD,
                                   DUE_DATE DPG_DD,
                                   BATCH_CLOSE_DATE DPG_BCD
                            FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                           WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                   AND TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                            (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                             TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                   AND attribute1 = 'DUMPING'
                        ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) DPG
                    ON XX.NO_OKP = DPG.NO_OKP
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                                RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A') no_okp,
                                attribute1 Line,
                                DECODE (batch_status,
                                        '1', 'Inspect',
                                        '2', 'Release',
                                        '3', 'Complete',
                                        'Close')
                                   Batch_status,
                                CREATION_DATE,
                                PLAN_START_DATE SAC_PSD,
                                ACTUAL_START_DATE SAC_ASD,
                                PLAN_CMPLT_DATE SAC_PCD,
                                ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE SAC_ACD,
                                DUE_DATE SAC_DD,
                                BATCH_CLOSE_DATE SAC_BCD
                         FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                        WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                                AND TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                         (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                          TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                AND attribute1 IN ('SACHET D', 'SACHET A')
                     ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) SAC
                 ON XX.NO_OKP = SAC.NO_OKP
              LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (  SELECT   DISTINCT
                             RTRIM (SUBSTR (BATCH_NO, 4, 4), 'A') no_okp,
                             attribute1 Line,
                             DECODE (batch_status,
                                     '1', 'Inspect',
                                     '2', 'Release',
                                     '3', 'Complete',
                                     'Close')
                                Batch_status,
                             CREATION_DATE,
                             PLAN_START_DATE BPE_PSD,
                             ACTUAL_START_DATE BPE_ASD,
                             PLAN_CMPLT_DATE BPE_PCD,
                             ACTUAL_CMPLT_DATE BPE_ACD,
                             DUE_DATE BPE_DD,
                             BATCH_CLOSE_DATE BPE_BCD
                      FROM   GME_BATCH_HEADER
                     WHERE   ORGANIZATION_ID = 84
                             AND TO_CHAR (creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') IN
                                      (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 7, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
                                       TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 8, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
                             AND attribute1 = 'SACHET E'
                  ORDER BY   CREATION_DATE DESC) BPE
              ON XX.NO_OKP = BPE.NO_OKP
   ORDER BY   xx.no_okp ASC;
```

Where is the fault ?how to get the specific error code ?

Comment: Use `show errors` (if Toad supports that) or query the `user_errors` view to see the actual problem.

Comment: You should do some basic investigation before posting the entire query for us to fix.

Comment: Why to_char(creation_date........? No need to convert date to char, specially if that column is indexed. You should have used creation_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 8 and creation_date < trunc(sysdate) - 6... This is not related to the question, but it can seriously degrade performance of the view.

Answer (score 1):

To find the specific errors, either:

1. Test it without the `force` keyword.
2. Test it without the `create view ... as` part, i.e. test the `select` part on its own.
3. In SQL*Plus or compatible tools, execute the following command while connected as the APPS user: `show errors view kmi_okp_track_v` (or include the schema if executing from a DBA account)
4. Query `user_errors` while connected as the APPS user (or `dba_errors` if executing from a DBA account).

Example:

```
SQL> create or replace force view demo_view as
  2  select nosuchcolumn from dual;

Warning: View created with compilation errors.
```

Test without the `force` keyword:

```
SQL> create or replace view demo_view as
  2  select nosuchcolumn from dual;
select nosuchcolumn from dual
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "NOSUCHCOLUMN": invalid identifier
```

Testing the `select` statement on its own:

```
SQL> select nosuchcolumn from dual;
select nosuchcolumn from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "NOSUCHCOLUMN": invalid identifier
```

Using `show errors`:

```
SQL> show errors view demo_view
Errors for VIEW DEMO_VIEW:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0      ORA-00904: "NOSUCHCOLUMN": invalid identifier
```

Querying `user_errors` view:

```
SQL> col text format a70

SQL> select text from user_errors e
  2  where  e.name = 'DEMO_VIEW'
  3  order by e.sequence;

TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ORA-00904: "NOSUCHCOLUMN": invalid identifier
```

For deployment scripts, I would include the `force` keyword and `show errors` at the end.

Comment: Now i get the error code: ora-01791: not a selected expression

Comment: thanks all, I found an error in my script, in this script:

(SELECT distinct rtrim(SUBSTR(BATCH_NO,4,4),'A') no_okp,ATTRIBUTE1 LINE--,CREATION_DATE 
FROM GME_BATCH_HEADER WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID=84 and TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
in (TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-4, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-3, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-2, 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC)XX

i do order by creation_date but in my script column creation_date was not select

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your syntax, and you may create this view in your current user, provided the schema prefix `APPS.` is removed from `CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW APPS.KMI_OKP_TRACK_V`.

If you need to create this view from your current schema, you need more prefixes for `GME_BATCH_HEADER` and the creation privilege should be granted for `APPS` schema.

Comment: thanks all, I found an error in my script, in this script: 

(SELECT distinct rtrim(SUBSTR(BATCH_NO,4,4),'A') no_okp,ATTRIBUTE1 LINE--,CREATION_DATE FROM GME_BATCH_HEADER WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID=84 and TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') in (TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-4, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-3, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-2, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC)XX 

i do order by creation_date but in my script column creation_date was not select,
so the problem was solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Barbaros said your query look good.

But here a problem i ran into - perhaps it's your problem, too.

```
-- This will work
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MySchema.MyView
(
    MyColumn
)
AS
    SELECT "MyColumn" FROM myTable;

-- This won't - because of the delimiter (';') in our variable myquery
DECLARE
    myquery VARCHAR2(2000) :=
'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MySchema.MyView
(
    MyColumn
)
AS
    SELECT "MyColumn" FROM myTable;'    
;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE myquery;
END;
```

If you `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` a query, it must not have a delimiter - neither `;` nor `/`. This is not allowed because you always have to run a single statement, not a list of statement seperated by a delimiter.

The correct version is this:

```
-- This won't - because of the delimiter (';') in our variable myquery
DECLARE
    myquery VARCHAR2(2000) :=
'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MySchema.MyView
(
    MyColumn
)
AS
    SELECT "MyColumn" FROM myTable' -- no ';' here
;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE myquery;
END;
```

Fun-fact: Your View will be created and will work after a recompile.

Comment: thanks all, I found an error in my script, in this script: 

(SELECT distinct rtrim(SUBSTR(BATCH_NO,4,4),'A') no_okp,ATTRIBUTE1 LINE--,CREATION_DATE FROM GME_BATCH_HEADER WHERE ORGANIZATION_ID=84 and TO_CHAR(creation_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') in (TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-5, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-4, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-3, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-1, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_CHAR(sysdate-2, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) ORDER BY CREATION_DATE DESC)XX 

i do order by creation_date but in my script column creation_date was not select,
so the problem was solved, thanks